# Getting Information From Lazy Initialized Exports

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

I want to bind a (Imported with MEF2 Convention) `IEnumerable<Lazy<IModule>>` collection to a Menu.

IModule is an interface to ViewModels located in an external project.

My problem is, with `Lazy<T>`, I cannot figure out how I can obtain a MenuName (and what MenuParent it belongs under, if any) without instantiating the object, and this defeats the purpose of Lazy Initialization (there are a lot of Modules and each user needs to use a very small number). I use Caliburn.Micro for MVVM.

I have thought about storing the Menu structure in the Database, but this is added points of failure when other developers create new Modules or remove obsolete Modules, and is similar to hardcoding the menu.

MEF Export:

```cs
RegistrationBuilder builder = new RegistrationBuilder()
builder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IModule>.Export<IModule>
```

MenuViewModel:

```cs
private IEnumerable<Lazy<IModule>> _modules;

public MenuViewModel(IEnumerable<Lazy<IModule>> modules)
{
    _modules = modules;
}

public IEnumerable<Lazy<IModule>> Modules
{
    get { return _modules; }
    set { _modules = value; }
}
```

I stopped here, because there is nothing to bind to. `Lazy<IModule>` doesn't contain any information about the type bound to it.

I am looking for a strategy to allow for MEF Exports of 3rd party plugins, the names of which I can display on a Menu, without hardcoding the menu.

Comment: The `Value` property of the `Lazy<IModule>` will initialize and return an `IModule` that you can bind to. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: @mm8 I need to create a menu, available when the user logs in, from information about these Modules. If I instantiate all of them, doesn't that defeat the purpose of Lazy loading?

Comment: Of course you need to instantiate them in order to be able to get any information from them. Instead of using a `Lazy`, you could bind to some light-weight view model object.

Comment: That's what I think I'm going to end up doing. Plugin Development will involve them writing the ViewModel/View classes, implementing the IModule interface, and another POD class containing the stuff needed during startup, implementing some other interface. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Value` property of the `Lazy<IModule>` will initialize and return an `IModule`, but of course you need to instantiate them in order to be able to get any information from them.

Instead of using a `Lazy<T>`, you could bind to some light-weight view model object. This means that you will have to create an additional type for each module but this shouldn't be an issue given your requirements.